# DMD: link to libc.a? Or core.simd info?

Tags: c, linker, d, dmd

I'm guessing No, but I want to here from the community because I'm not real experienced with this stuff. Is it possible to link with /etc/lib/libc.a (I'm on Linux x64) with DMD?

My reason is, I'm trying to get hardware SSE intrinsics to work (beyond simple addition/subtraction/etc), so it would be great if I could just write:

```d
// simdTest.d
import core.simd;

extern (C) float4 _mm_hadd_ps(float4 a, float4 b); // example

void main()
{
    float4 a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    float4 b = [1, 1, 1, 1];
    float4 c = _mm_hadd_ps(a, b);
}
```

and compile with:

```
dmd /usr/lib/libc.a simdTest.d
```

but I get all kinds of linking errors I don't know how to make sense of. Again, I'm guess there's something preventing me from doing this, but if not I'd like to know how to go about it.

### Or...

Really all I need is to get vectors working. The above C function does exist (sorta) in core.simd, but I can't get it to work (not sure if bug, or something i'm doing wrong). Here's my simple code:

```d
import core.simd;

void main()
{
    void16 a, b;
    void16 c = __simd(XMM.HADDPS, a, b);
}
```

but the compiler gives me an:

```
Internal error: e2ir.c 3817
```

when compiling it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `_mm_hadd_ps` is not a function that you can link with, it is an intrinsic. It can only be used with compilers that support that intrinsic, and DMD does not.
2. The compiler error is not your fault. Any `Internal error` is a bug in the compiler and should be reported to the D bug database.

Answer (score 2):

@F i L : When I try your code with latest DMD compiler (2.060) I get an *expected* error : `Error: void does not have a default initializer`. Check it yourself: http://www.dpaste.dzfl.pl/fb6cd879

D does not initialise void values.

If you use some other type it will work:

```
import core.simd;

void main()  {
  // void16 does not work because void16 is not initialised, testing with ubyte16
  ubyte16 a, b;
  ubyte16 c = __simd(XMM.HADDPS, a, b);
}
```

You can test it here - http://www.dpaste.dzfl.pl/4ea6517b

Ah, and to answer your first question - your D applications are already linked to libc by default, and it is not in /etc/lib/libc.a (unless you have a weird admin who puts system libraries into /etc/lib), it is typically either in /lib or in /usr/lib (especially after the recent merge of /lib into /usr/lib).